# Order posts by descending for all categories

Tags: wordpress, categories

I would like to order my posts by descending for all categories in my category.php

For the moment I have a code that orders my posts by descending but category per category. 
So if someone add a new category, the posts of this new category will not be ordered by descending.

Here's my code :

```
<?php if (in_category('food')) : query_posts( array( 'category_name' => 'food','order' => 'DESC') ); endif; ?>
<?php if (in_category('things')) : query_posts( array( 'category_name' => 'things','order' => 'DESC') ); endif; ?>
<?php if (in_category('story')) : query_posts( array( 'category_name' => 'story','order' => 'DESC') ); endif; ?>
```

Is there a simple code that order my posts for all category in one time ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems like this code works :

```
<?php global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'category__in' => array(get_query_var('cat')), 'order' => 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'title' ));
query_posts( $args );
?>
```